# lodash data manipulation challenge

Tags: lodash

a challenge for the lodash experts out there:
I am turning that data structure:

```
{ 
 file_caption_71: 'lounge',
 file_description_71: 'View of the lounge from the kitchen',
 file_caption_72: 'whatever', 
 file_description_72: 'Some description of the whatever photo shown' 
}
```

into this one:

```
[{ 
    id: 71,
    data: {
        caption: 'lounge',
        description: 'View of the lounge from the kitchen'
    }
}, { 
    id: 72,
    data: {
        caption: 'whatever',
        description: 'Some description of the whatever photo shown'
    }
}]
```

with some messy code but what I would like is to be able to do that in a elegant way with some lodash magic. So if anyone would like to display their lodash skill that would be appreciated: I've tried and failed to come up with a decent looking piece of code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `_.transform()` to change the object into a new map object by id, then extract the sub objects into an array using values:

```js
var data = {
  file_caption_71: 'lounge',
  file_description_71: 'View of the lounge from the kitchen',
  file_caption_72: 'whatever',
  file_description_72: 'Some description of the whatever photo shown'
};

var result = _(data).transform(function(result, value, key) {
  var keys = key.split('_');
  var id = keys[2];
  var dataType = keys[1];
  
  result[id] = result[id] || { id: parseInt(id, 10), data: {} };
  
  result[id].data[dataType] = value;
  
  return result;
}).values().value();

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.16.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = {
  file_caption_71: 'lounge',
  file_description_71: 'View of the lounge from the kitchen',
  file_caption_72: 'whatever',
  file_description_72: 'Some description of the whatever photo shown'
};


const extract = (data) => {
  const _finalResult = _.reduce(data, (result, value, key) => {
    const [prefix, type, id] = key.split('_');
    _.set(result, `${id}.${type}`, value);
    return result;
  }, {});

  return _.map(_finalResult, (data, id) => ({id, data}));
}

console.log('result', extract(data));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.16.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```